# Symfony2 & PHPUnit Code Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am currently testing my Symfony2 project by using this xml configuration, which works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src/IRC/*Bundle/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

I'd like to have code coverage reports generated at the same time, so I added this to the configuration:

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="/var/www/manager/dev/code_coverage/"/>
</logging>
```

When I try to run the tests, PHPUnit never gets started, I don't even get the `Configuration read from /foo/bar/symfony/app/phpunit.xml.dist` message.  I tried letting it run all night, and it never got started.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to run the phpunit with this option --coverage-html <dir> - You can see others options here [Chapter 3. The Command-Line Test Runner](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions)

Comment: @RicardoSimas I have the same issue when removing the logging from the XML code and passing it as a command line argument.  Should be the same either way, right?

Comment: Yes, both are equal. The user that you are using to run the PHPUnit have permission to write in the folder target="/var/www/manager/dev/code_coverage/"?